# How to copy or update from one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. `user` and `user_new`
the `user` contains the old data.
the `user_new` contains the new data.
I want to sync the `user_new` to `user`.

1. if the data exist in `user_new` and not exist in `user`,then insert to `user`.
2. if the data exist in `user` and `user_new`, then update.(compare with the column `id`)

what's the fast sql to do it?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Which version of sql server?

Comment: @Dozer are you a Data Migration team Member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on any server version -

```
   -- 1) Insert new record

        INSERT INTO old_table(id, column)
        SELECT n.id, n.column
        FROM new_table n
        LEFT JOIN old_table o ON n.id = o.id
        WHERE o.id IS NULL

   -- 2) Update existed record

        UPDATE o
        SET column = n.column
        FROM old_table o
        JOIN new_table n ON n.id = o.id
```

Answer (score 1):

From Sql Server 2008 onwards you can use `Merge` syntax

```
MERGE user target
USING user_new source
ON taget.ID = source.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET target.Column= source.Column1,target.column2=source.column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (ID,Column1,Column2)
VALUES (source.ID,source.column1,source.column2);
```

or you can use the below query

```
INSERT INTO user(ID,column1,column2) 
SELECT ID,column1,column2 FROM user_new  AS source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = source.ID);

UPDATE target SET ...
FROM user AS target
INNER JOIN user_new AS source
ON target.ID = source.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `insert` and `update` in a single query you have to do in seperate

```
select * from user where user_id not in (select user_new.user_id from user_new )
```

this query results the data for insert query similarly u have to update by replacing `not in` to `in`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need a [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) if you have sql server 2008+.